# How can I prevent MVVM Light Messenger to Not track Registered Object

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, messenger

I have a Good Model:

```
public class Good 
{
    public int GoodId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And a GoodListViewModel :

```
public class GoodListViewModel()
{
    // ...

    ObservableCollection<Good> goods;

    public Good SelectedGood
    {
        get { return selectedGood; }
        set
        {
            selectedGood = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedGood");
        }
    }

    // ...

    //This will send selected Good to GoodDetailViewModel For Edit
    Messenger.Default.Send(SelectedGood, "GoodForEdit");

    // ...

}
```

And a GoodDetailViewModel :

```
public class GoodDetailViewModel
{
    public GoodDetailViewModel(IGoodService gs)
    {
        // ...
        Messenger.Default.Register<Good>(this,"GoodForEdit", instance);
    }

    public void instance(Good good)
    {
        good.Name = "ChangedName";
    }
}
```

I use MVVM Light Messenger For send and recive and also ViewmodelLocator ..

**Questions**

for example I open a good for edit and change some data but do not save it and cancel editing ... here changed data comeback to GoodListViewModel !!!

why this happend ... because of ObservableCollection propertyChange or Messenger implementation ?

Comment: could you please rephrase your question, what you mean by save and cancel? put the logic related to those operation !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that you don't produce a copy of your instance of `Good` here. What you effectively do is to send your original instance to the `GoodDetailViewModel`. If the `GoodDetailViewModel` makes any changes to the `Good` instance, the `GoodListViewModel` will see them as well.

You would have to [implement `ICloneable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the `Good` class to avoid this behavior - then you could send the copy, edit it, and then send it back (given that you don't want to discard all changes).

Comment: you right ... But this is a bad things ... I send an object to a viewmodel for editing ... why should sender see changes ?!!! ... all changes should comeback only **if** I want to comeback ... Am I mistake ? ... I send a copy of object (instance) to a class and change it on that class ,But not return it with method ... why the orginal one accept changes ?!!!!

Comment: This is because you have exactly the **same** object in both classes, you are just sending a reference around. You shoud learn about value types and reference types in C#: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx